# Is there any way to get the data returned from the class (apiData) in "Dart"?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class _CategoriesPageState extends State<CategoriesPage> {
  List postsData;
  int categoryID;

  void getApiData() async {
    //Get posts api data
    ApiData apiData = ApiData(
      apiUrl: 'http://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=$categoryID',
    );

    dynamic responseBody = await apiData.getData();
    setState(() {
      postsData = json.decode(responseBody);
    });
  }
```

Now I want to reach the (apiData) in my widget, but because it's inside void function I cant use it.

Comment: create that variable outside function. i mean in class not in function.

Comment: Can you show me by writing the code, please

Comment: List postsData;
  int categoryID;
ApiData apiData;
  void getApiData() async {
    //Get posts api data
    apiData = ApiData(..

Comment: Thank you a lot, @VirenVVarasadiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a variable outside function, so that you can access by class object.

```
class _CategoriesPageState extends State<CategoriesPage> {
  List postsData;
  ApiData apiData 
  int categoryID;

  void getApiData() async {
    //Get posts api data
    apiData = ApiData(
      apiUrl: 'http://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=$categoryID',
    );

    dynamic responseBody = await apiData.getData();
    setState(() {
      postsData = json.decode(responseBody);
    });
  }
```